# Excel formula help, exponental

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I write this formula in excel. Tried a few times but it didnt work as i expected.

[image: this is the formula]

k = 0.25
fee = a range of % ( from 1% to 10%)

Ideally i see a curve that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you show some of your attempted formulas?

Comment: Also show your data sample.

Comment: there is something wrong with the formula if you expect `10%` to return `0`: `-1*(.01*.25)^2` returns: `-0.00000625` and `e^-0.00000625` is `0.999375195` not `0`.